# Convenient method for statically rendering 3d shapes into image files

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

My basic problem is to generate 2d renders of 3d objects, such as one could accomplish with openGL or DirectX. However I have no interest in displaying the rendered objects to the screen, only to generate the shaded/ textured/ rotated images as bitmaps (not necessarily written to disk). This process is likely to be a problematic bottleneck in my design, so I would prefer to keep my solution as compact as possible (ie, don't waste the time sending the image to the screen), and would be most pleased if I could make use of hardware-accelerated rendering. Does anyone know of a convenient library or tool to help in this?

Right now I would prefer a C/C++ option, however speed is what I'm going for, so I'm willing to deal with ASM/ super optimized anything if it gets what I want the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a so called technique "rendering to texture". With OpenGL you can do it very easy. Take a look at example here: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html#example

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using "render to texture"

> This process is likely to be a problematic bottleneck in my design, so I would prefer to keep my solution as compact as possible (ie, don't waste the time sending the image to the screen)

If you want rendering to be fast, you want to use the GPU for this. Sending a image to the screen comes for free with those things. But reading an image back to the CPU memory, that is actually quite a bottleneck. But unavoidable in you case probably.